# how to make python urllib2 download file with authentication, gui (only showing downloaded file %) and resume capability?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, progress-bar, urllib2, resume-download

so far i have done this:

```
import urllib2, base64, os

def dl():
    dwnld="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/user/file.zip"
    username="user"
    password="pass"
    req=urllib2.Request(dwnld)
    base64str=base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
    req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64str)   
    result=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    with open(os.path.basename(dwnld), "wb") as local_file:
        local_file.write(result.read())
        local_file.close()

dl()
```

now i need a download progress window (gui) and resume capability added to it. help please.

Comment: tried tkinter but didnt know how.

Comment: As i know there is no option of providing authentication credentials and to download file. I ended up using 'curl' and calling it from os.system